# Full calendar loop with description

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with full calendar, it's not showing the description i dont know why.. my code is:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  buttonText: {
    today: 'hoy',
    month: 'mes',
    week: 'semana',
    day: 'día'
  },
  //Random default events
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>calendar/retrieve",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
          start: start.format(),
          end: end.format()
      },
      success: function(doc) 
      {
        var events = [];
        var eventRender = [];
        if(!doc.result)
        {
          $.each($.parseJSON(doc), function() {
             events.push({
                      title: this.description,
                      start: this.start_date,
                      end: this.end_date,
                      backgroundColor: "#0073b7",
                      description: 'second description',
                      borderColor: "#0073b7"
                    });
          });
        }
        callback(events);
      }
    });
  },
```

I'm getting the information from a database and then I show it in the calendar... I put description: 'some description...',  but when I see the calendar it is not displaying that, why? or if you know another way to put a description, a tooltip maybe i dunno... I have seen examples but without a loop and i need how to put with a loop..

I am using the fullcalendar version 3.4.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change `$.each loop` like this:

```
$.each(JSON.stringify(doc), function (i, d) {
 events.push({
      title: doc[i].description,
      start: doc[i].start_date,
      end: doc[i].end_date,
      backgroundColor: "#0073b7",
      description: 'second description',
      borderColor: "#0073b7"
    });
});
```

Comment: The thing is that description is not comming from the database... description is written there.. but it is not showing description.. title is working and date, etc but description no..